# Problems Linking Between PHP Pages

Tags: php, session

I am creating a PHP application for the first time.  I am currently trying to create a navigation bar linking between each of the pages. I have a `login.php` file which posts the username/password to a `dataaccess.php` file handling the login which returns a unique userID.  If the login is successful (i.e. `userID != -1` is returned) this code is called:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $UserID;
include('Index.php');
```

And at the top of `Index.php` I Check:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userID']))
{
    include('login.php');
    exit;
}
```

In `Index.php`, I have a navigation bar containing the link:

```
<a class="Link" id="nLink" name="Index" href="Index.php" target="">Index</a>
```

This link obviously links to itself but the session variable no longer exists and redirects to the `login.php` file again.

1. Should I just make it `href="#"`?
2. Change the logic in the beginning of `Index.php`?
3. Is there a best practice for handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the top of index.php?

```
session_start();
```

Should be above that, on the very top of all pages that use $_SESSION

User-defined variables may have to start with a lower case. ie $userID

Comment: Login.php posts the credentials to Submit.php which handles calling the db functions in the dataaccess.php file.  If successful Submit.php calls include('Index.php');. Basically, how do I prevent someone from just accessing Index.php without logging in?

Comment: Wrap the content you want to protect with an else statement after !isset($_SESSION['userID']). Or add a redirect inside the else statement to the protected content with header( 'Location: URL_HERE' )